# how to helm-projectile-grep for exact string?

Tags: projectile, helm-projectile, helm-grep

How can I direct `helm-projectile-ag` and `helm-projectile-grep` to search for an exact string?

If I enclose a string in quotes, I get no results. If I don't, I get fuzzy matching.

Answer (score 4):

Fuzzy matching should be switched off by default, but if you have a space character in your pattern it will turn fuzzy matching on.

If your query didn't have spaces, check your emacs config and make sure `helm-ag-fuzzy-match` isn't set to `t`.

For space characters in your pattern you should use the regex `\s`.